# Can there be any {A,B,C,D} distinct primes such that A*B = C*D?

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

Could a product of 2 primes equal the product of two other different primes?

Either yes, or no, is there any proof of that?

Comment: The fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Suppose that $ab = cd$ for primes $a,b,c,d$. By the definition of a prime $a \mid ab = cd$ implies that $a \mid c$ or $a \mid d$. Since $c,d$ are prime we must have WLOG $a = c$. Dividing by $c$ gives that $b = d$. Hence the claim.